# Fetch Top In App Purchase From AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

Is there any way I can get "Top In App Purchases" from App Store to display it in my app?

For example: http://itunes.apple.com/vn/app/wild-blood/id451403547?mt=8

I want to get:

Top In App Purchases

WARRIOR'S TREASURE $4.99

SMALL TREASURE     $1.99

KNIGHT'S TREASURE  $9.99

KING'S TREASURE    $19.99

DEVIL'S TREASURE   $49.99

GOD'S TREASURE     $99.99

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score -1):

Yes very simple, find any RSS reader code... and read this
For top 10 free apps
http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=10/xml
or for top 10 paid apps
http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/toppaidapplications/limit=10/xml

Or make your own rss with iTunes Store RSS Feed Generator
http://itunes.apple.com/rss

Comment: @SunB Have you found a solution?

Comment: @iTarek The question is to fetch the in-app purchases of a particular app not top free applications.